# Can two networks be activated on the same physical connection in network-manager?

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

I want access to two networks:

- a PPPoE network: for external computers (www, etc.)

  - IP(dhcp), DNS, default route
- a LAN for access to other local computers (local file sharing)

  - IP(dhcp), no DNS, only LAN route

Both networks are setup through the same Ethernet connection.

One way of accessing both networks at the same time is to connect to PPPoE from network-manager, and add the LAN info by hand:

- add an IP on eth0
- add a route for traffic to that network

I can configure two distinct connections in NetworkManager, but because both are on the same physical (Ethernet) network, selecting one of them makes the other one disconnect => can't have both of them at the same time.

Is there a way to have both of the active simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work with an ethernet port managed by NM.
I'm no expert and am new to NM and Ubuntu -so be advised.

Using Ubuntu 12.04
Added a script: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/wjw-alias-eth1
(an edited version of installed file: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown).

NM docs say scripts in dispatcher.d are run in alphabetic sort order, so name your
added file so it runs last.

In my case eth1 is behind a router which assigns an IP# via 'static' DHCP.
I need a 2nd IP# on the same LAN segment so I can run two DLNA servers at the same time. (Mythtv and Serviio in my case.) It seems DLNA servers must each bind to a 
different IP#.  I wanted to keep NM managing eth1 to keep using its built in goodies

my added script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Script for nm to add an alias eth1:0 and multicast routing on eth1 up---wjw

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "$0: called with no interface" 1>&2
    exit 1;
fi
        eth1="eth1"
if [ "$1" != "$eth1" ]; then
        exit 0;
fi


# Run the right scripts
case "$2" in
    up|vpn-up)
        ifconfig eth1:0 192.168.10.10  netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.10.255
        route add -net 239.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev eth1:0
        ;;
    down|vpn-down|hostname|dhcp4-change|dhcp6-change)
        # Do nothing more
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$0: called with unknown action \`$2'" 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias. Both of which are on the same subnet. You can then assign your services accordingly.

```
ifconfig eth0:0 10.0.0.3
ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.4
```

Comment: Yep, that works, but I was looking for a complete network-manager based solution, with no cli involved. But I guess if I automate the creation of the alias on start up, no cli will be needed afterwards.